# Multiple sitemaps with php

Tags: php, xml, sitemap

I have a website to which I add a log of pages on a regular basis. Currently I am iterating through my database to get a few hundred URLs and then adding them to sitemap-1 then getting the next few hundred and adding them to sitemap-2. I am doing this all by hand.

I would like to use a while loop that creates all the new pages and inserts them into the database. It should check my current sitemap-x to determine if the URL count threshold is reached, and then create a new sitemap++ and start adding the pages or just add on to the current sitemap.

How can I accomplish this?

I have got some code to create the sitemap but im not sure how to check if it is full with 2000 urls then move on to creating a new one.

```
<?php


/* create a dom document with encoding utf8 */
$domtree = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

/* create the root element of the xml tree */
$xmlRoot = $domtree->createElement("urlset");
$xmlRoot -> appendChild(new DomAttr('xmlns',  'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9'));
$xmlRoot -> appendChild(new DomAttr('xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'));
$xmlRoot -> appendChild(new DomAttr('xsi:schemaLocation', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd'));

/* append it to the document created */
$xmlRoot = $domtree->appendChild($xmlRoot);

/* tehloop */
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $currentTrack = $domtree->createElement("url");
    $currentTrack = $xmlRoot->appendChild($currentTrack);
    $currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('loc','website'));
    $currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('changefreq','weekly'));
    $currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('priority','1.0'));
}

/* save the xml sitemap */
$domtree->formatOutput = true;
$domtree->preserveWhitespace = false;
$domtree->save('sitemap.xml'); 

?>
```

Comment: what's the site map used for?

Answer (score 0):

```
$tracks = array();
$count = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if($count >= 2000){
        $count = 0;
        array_push($currentTrack);
        unset($currentTrack);
        //Reset your domtree object here too...
    }
    $currentTrack = $domtree->createElement("url");
    $currentTrack = $xmlRoot->appendChild($currentTrack);
    $currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('loc','website'));
    $currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('changefreq','weekly'));
    $currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('priority','1.0'));
}

//Now for each array index loop through file creation 
for($i = 0; $i < $tracks.length; $i++){
    /* save the xml sitemap */
    $domtree->formatOutput = true;
    $domtree->preserveWhitespace = false;
    $domtree->save('sitemap' . $i . '.xml'); 
}
```

You'll have to add code here to reset your domtree and do the appropriate fixes to get it working but you get the point.

Comment: Reset the domtree object by just copying the domroot and xmlroot variables again?

Comment: Well, since you're spitting out files here I'd say do the same thing as with the $currentTrack variable. Unset them, and reinitialize them. This will be good for the future when you need to be able to set different attributes for each DOM. Also, encapsulate the DOM tree creation in a function and you'll have less maintenance woes and cleaner code.